# SElinux Android message interpretation

Tags: android, selinux

I am unable to make sense of this message which I get on my android application. Any experts in the house ?

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:2233): avc: denied { create } for name="access_control.new_commit.cv" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:fuse:s0:c512,c768 tclass=fifo_file permissive=0
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The given SELinux violation:

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:2233): avc: denied { create } for name="access_control.new_commit.cv" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:fuse:s0:c512,c768 tclass=fifo_file permissive=0
```

Below I'll try to give explanation of important parts of above violation:

`denied { create }` : **Operation Permission State** : The denied permission that was requested / executed. In this case, it is a *create* operation. SELinux denying permission to execute *create* *dir*/*file* operation.

`name="access_control.new_commit.cv"`: **Target name** : The name of the target (in this case, the *file/dir* name) which your application, probably, trying to create.

`scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0` : **Source Context** : The Source Context for this security violation. This indicates which *domain/proces*s is trying to execute *create* functionality. Here, `untrusted_app` applications are those which are launched by zygote

`tcontext=u:object_r:fuse:s0` : **Target Context** : The security context of the target resource (in this case the file). Here, the source tried to create *file* in *Fuse file system* which has been denied.

`tclass=fifo_file` : **Target Class** : The class of the target.

**In one sentence**, SELinux denied the permission to `untrusted_app` to `create` the `access_control.new_commit.cv` file in `fuse`.

From Google source, check SEPolicy file [untrusted_app.te](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-n-preview-2/untrusted_app.te#160) how the permission has been denied.

NB: If you any suggestion with the answer, let me know.

Comment: Thanks.This happened when I try to write to realm file the first time. But when I come around second time I am able to write to REalm DB. So why does it happens only first time time around when application is launched.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Validating SELinux  |  Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate), for message:

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:2233): avc: denied { create } for name="access_control.new_commit.cv" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:fuse:s0:c512,c768 tclass=fifo_file permissive=0
```

the key info is:

- `Action`: **create**
- `Actor`=`scontext`=`source context`: **untrusted_app**
- `Object`=`tcontext`=`target context`: **fuse**

  - `object_r`=`object read` ?
- `Result`=`tclass`=`target class`: **fifo_file**=FIFO file
- `permissive`=`permissive mode`: **0** -> **NOT** permissive mode

  - -> is Enforce mode ?

translated to human readable sentence:

**untrusted_app** want to **create** a **fifo_file** for **fuse**

(But enforce mode of Android SELinux **STOP** it for no permission, so you see above logcat log info)

Answer (score 2):

I could add that running audit2allow on the error message will give you a suggestion on how to update the untrusted_app.te file.

Dump dmesg to text file:

```
dmesg > /sdcard/dmesg.txt
```

```
cat dmesg.txt | grep avc | audit2allow
```

will give you the following result in this case:

```
#============= untrusted_app ==============
allow untrusted_app fuse:fifo_file create;
```

Add this line to untrusted_app.te and rebuild the Android kernel!

Comment: `audit2allow` isn't present on my Android device, so I `adb pull`ed the `dmesg.txt` to WSL. I had to install `audit2allow` using `sudo apt install policycoreutils-python-utils`. I also needed to grab the policy file `adb pull /sys/fs/selinux/policy`, then change the call to `audit2allow -p policy`.

Comment: From the [AOSP docs](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate#using_audit2allow), "_Note: audit2allow is not provided as part of AOSP anymore. Use the package supplied by your Linux distribution (package policycoreutils-python-utils on Debian and Ubuntu)._"

Comment: Also note: untrusted_app.te [is located in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64275449/1174169) `/system/sepolicy/private/untrusted_app.te`, which is not accessible (at least for me) on non-rooted devices.