# SE Linux Android 9 AOSP: Adding a permission in system/sepolicy/private/untrusted_app.te file leading to a build failure

Tags: build, android-source, android-9.0-pie, selinux

I am working on **Android9 AOSP**, when I add a permission in my untrusted_app.te (located in `system/sepolicy/private/untrusted_app.te`), my build fails.

**Error:**

```
system/sepolicy/private/untrusted_app.te:27:ERROR 'unknown type xyz_block_device' at token ';' on line....
```

The permission that am adding is `allow untrusted_app xyz_block_device:blk_file { read write };`
in file system/sepolicy/private/untrusted_app.te

Can anyone please guide me where to define xyz_block_device , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you see the error is that the xyz_block_device is not defined. for this you need to go the file_contexts and define your xyz_block_device like this:

```
/dev/yourblockdevice  u:object_r:block_device:s0
```

and then you can add your rule to untrusted_app.te.

Note: I have to mention that changing the system SEPolicy is not recommended nor safe, it is better to add file named untrusted_app.te to your target tree. (/device/vendor/model).