# What is the cause of this log message in android studio

Tags: java, android, video, webview

I am trying to play videos using webview and whenever the play button is clicked, i get the following in my log.

```
W/Chrome_InProcGp: type=1400 audit(0.0:35414): avc: denied { call } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:mtk_hal_pq:s0 tclass=binder permissive=0
W/vendor.mediatek.hardware.pq@2.0::PictureQuality: IPictureQuality: cannot call into hwbinder service: Status(EX_TRANSACTION_FAILED): 'FAILED_TRANSACTION: '; No permission? Check for selinux denials.
W/Chrome_InProcGp: type=1400 audit(0.0:35415): avc: denied { call } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:mtk_hal_pq:s0 tclass=binder permissive=0
W/vendor.mediatek.hardware.pq@2.0::PictureQuality: IPictureQuality: cannot call into hwbinder service: Status(EX_TRANSACTION_FAILED): 'FAILED_TRANSACTION: '; No permission? Check for selinux denials.
W/IMGSRV: IMGeglCreateImageKHR:1104: 640x368, crop to (0,0)-(640,360)
W/IMGSRV: IMGeglCreateImageKHR:1104: 640x368, crop to (0,0)-(640,360)
W/vendor.mediatek.hardware.pq@2.0::PictureQuality: IPictureQuality: cannot call into hwbinder service: Status(EX_TRANSACTION_FAILED): 'FAILED_TRANSACTION: '; No permission? Check for selinux denials.
W/Chrome_InProcGp: type=1400 audit(0.0:35416): avc: denied { call } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:mtk_hal_pq:s0 tclass=binder permissive=0
W/Chrome_InProcGp: type=1400 audit(0.0:35417): avc: denied { call } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:mtk_hal_pq:s0 tclass=binder permissive=0
W/vendor.mediatek.hardware.pq@2.0::PictureQuality: IPictureQuality: cannot call into hwbinder service: Status(EX_TRANSACTION_FAILED): 'FAILED_TRANSACTION: '; No permission? Check for selinux denials.
W/IMGSRV: IMGeglCreateImageKHR:1104: 640x368, crop to (0,0)-(640,360)
W/Chrome_InProcGp: type=1400 audit(0.0:35418): avc: denied { call } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:mtk_hal_pq:s0 tclass=binder permissive=0
W/vendor.mediatek.hardware.pq@2.0::PictureQuality: IPictureQuality: cannot call into hwbinder service: Status(EX_TRANSACTION_FAILED): 'FAILED_TRANSACTION: '; No permission? Check for selinux denials.
```

Please any help will be appreciated

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45003607/334402